# HTTP: What response to return when change of password is required?

Tags: rest, http

I am working on a system in which I can create a user in it with the system admin user, logout, and then login with the new user I created. 
Then it returns to me with a "please reset your password before the first login" window and gives me a form of changing my password.

I am an automation engineer who needs to automate this process.
When I sent the login message, I received a response which seems to me very erroneous:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

content-type: text/plain

allow: false

content-length: 69

x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 144

date: Tue, 07 Jan 2020 13:10:03 GMT

server: istio-envoy


Internal Server Error:

Status message: Bad Request. status code: 400
```

I just want to hear your ideas what should the developer return in this case?
 What would be the best way to do this?

Is returning 200 ok with a header of status defining:

```
status: success\reset_pw_needed\etc...
```

will be a good attitude?

Or is there some adequate code among the 3XX or 4XX families?

Thanks

Comment: What variety of authentication are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think you need to use a status code to indicate this? There are not enough numbers in the 200-299 range to indicate every application-specific status in an HTTP response, and I really wish people would stop trying to shoehorn their application statuses into HTTP status code just because it looks cool and some of the big boys do it.

Definitely do not use the reason phrase for this, as that isn't meant to be interpreted by machines.

Just use a 200 to indicate the current request succeeded, and include an additional field in your **response body** to indicate the caller should update their password. Which isn't something a consuming program should have to do anyway, but whatever.

If it's consumers of flesh and blood you're concerned about, then just use the appropriate HTML output to indicate this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wish it could have been less aggressive in its tune...  Your suggestion is undoubtedly worthy.  Yet, a response code saying "Everything is fine till now, but you need to do something more" seems to me like a relevant response to many situations and not only to mine. All my sin was to ask if there something like this. That's all. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't meant in an agressive way, but if you roam the HTTP tag, you'll see dozens of questions like this per day. In HTTP, there is no status code for _"Well, this request is OK for now, but it won't be in the near future because your password is about to expire"_. It either is an error, or it isn't. If you want to provide additional information about the user or system status, you indeed use a response header or a field in the response body. The status code is about the current request.

Answer (score 0):

You bespoke client should be paying attention to the payload of the HTTP response.  Status codes are, like the headers, metadata that describe the semantics of the payload to *general-purpose* components, so that they can behave reasonably.

For example, if we were doing this with a web site, and you wanted to tell the human being that a change of password was required, then you write that in the html document.  The browser would render the document, the human would read it and know what to do.

The status code is for the *browser*, and also the cache, and any intermediate components that are able to read the request and response.

Status codes are part of the uniform interface, which is to say that the semantics of the code are the same for all resources.

Using [200 OK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) in circumstances where the server has refused to satisfy the request is *not* a good idea, because the primary meaning of 200 is that [the request has succeeded](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1).

Distinguishing correctly between 2xx and 4xx class codes is important because of [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).

Your best bet is probably [403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)

> the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response payload (if any).